# Add prefix to an integer

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to do the convert numeric value into string value in R?

For example:

```
c(1,2,3,4)
```

into

```
c("Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3", "Region 4")
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the commands `as.character` and `paste`

In your case, something like this would work

```
x <- c(1:4)
x <- as.character(x)
x <- paste("Region", x)
print(x)
[1] "Region 1" "Region 2" "Region 3" "Region 4"
```

Although I think R overloads its functions sufficiently so that this would work without first converting `x` to a character, as noted by the comment above. I included the `as.character` bit because the OP asked "does anyone know how to do the convert numeric value into string value in R".

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I need to run a Levene test but R always refused to execute and returned a warning that this is not possible for quantitative explanatory variables. When I used excel to do the conversion I asked before running the test, it ran smoothly. But I need to submit R code to my teacher, so your suggestion is perfect :D

Comment: For that you could also convert `x` to a factor by using `as.factor`